# using a 'environment' variable in java servlet running in tomcat container

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, environment-variables

I need to access a variable created in a shell script from a java servlet.
After reading the related posts in this forum I still haven't figured it out.
If I export a variable on my debian system (export var=foo123) and then I want to use 
this variable in my sevlet (System.getenv(var)) it always returns a null value.

I have already tried adding 'export var=foo123' in /etc/init.d/tomcat7 but to no succes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to use export, it should be enough to put:

```
 VARIABLE_NAME="variable_value"
```

in tomcat script file. And don't forget the ""!